# Is Flying Saucer's treatment of images in cells a bug?

Tags: html, flying-saucer, cellspacing

I managed to whittle my example down to the following (it uses some reasonably hefty data URLs but stackoverflow should flow them off the side nicely...):

```
static
{
    String oldValue = System.getProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs");
    if (oldValue == null)
    {
        System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "org.xhtmlrenderer.protocols");
    }
    else if (!oldValue.contains("org.xhtmlrenderer.protocols"))
    {
        System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", oldValue + "|org.xhtmlrenderer.protocols");
    }
}

@Test
public void testLegacyCellSpacing() throws Exception
{
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

    renderer.setDocumentFromString("<html>\n" +
                                   "  <head>\n" +
                                   "    <title>Some title</title>\n" +
                                   "  </head>\n" +
                                   "  <body>\n" +
                                   "    <div>\n" +
                                   "<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n" +
                                   "<tr>\n" +
                                   "<td>\n" +
                                   "   <img src=\"data:image/png;base64,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\" width=\"185\" height=\"83\"/>\n" +
                                   "</td>\n" +
                                   "</tr>\n" +
                                   "<tr>\n" +
                                   "<td>\n" +
                                   "   <img src=\"data:image/png;base64,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\" width=\"185\" height=\"84\"/>\n" +
                                   "</td>\n" +
                                   "</tr>\n" +
                                   "<tr>\n" +
                                   "<td>\n" +
                                   "   <img src=\"data:image/png;base64,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\" width=\"185\" height=\"83\"/>\n" +
                                   "</td>\n" +
                                   "</tr>\n" +
                                   "</table>\n" +
                                   "    </div>\n" +
                                   "  </body>\n" +
                                   "</html>", null);

    renderer.layout();

    File pdfFile = File.createTempFile("TestFlyingSaucer", ".pdf");
    OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(pdfFile));
    try
    {
        renderer.createPDF(output, true);
    }
    finally
    {
        output.close();
    }

    System.out.println(); // breakpointing here to look at the output.  no good assertions available for checking this problem yet. :(
}
```

This code runs, and generates a PDF which has incorrect spaces between each image.  I can't figure out what is causing the spaces, but I can't figure out if it's a bug either.  What I do know:

1. Web browsers don't show spaces between the images.
2. If you remove the images and replace it with something like a fixed size div, the problem magically goes away (this proves that flying saucer is doing the right thing with the legacy cellpadding and cellspacing attributes, which was my initial concern.)
3. If you add a 1 pixel border to the cells (`td { border: 1px solid red; }`), it shows that the extra space is outside the td elements.
4. If you remove the whitespace between `<td>` and `<img` the problem appears to vanish.

It seems odd to me that extra space *inside* the element could result in extra padding/margins *outside* the element.  Perhaps I'm completely misunderstanding HTML though, so I'm hoping that someone will set me straight here before I jam an issue in their tracker.

(Also: Preempting the typical knee-jerk answer of "don't use tables for that" - this is not my HTML, I'm trying to render real world HTML to PDF after cleaning it up.  This example shows post-cleanup HTML to rule out the problem being in the cleanup code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers are sensitive to white space in HTML in many places, including inside and in between elements, and even in places you would not expect.  For instance, if you had a `ul` with `li` elements, if you use CSS to style the items with `li {display:inline}` to make a horizontal menu, any white space between `</li>` and the next `<li>` will space the menu items apart!

In this particular case, seeing the white space indenting the first child element is certainly unusual but I can't say categorically if it would be considered a bug according to the HTML standards.  Your best solution is indeed to simply eliminate white space where it causes issues.